# CakePHP 3 - Multiple Auth

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 differents types of users : admins, customers and sellers, each one associated to a table. I can't merge the tables since they have differents fields.
I would like to use 3 differents auth, how can I do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on cakephp website that explains who is allowed to access what. Here is the link [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what).

Comment: I belive that this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555876/various-this-auth-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution using prefix and overriding the AppController inside the prefix subdirectory. 
That allows me to connect the user with a different table depending on the prefix.