# How to use multiple Auth components?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I configure a Auth component to "Admin page", using the users model. But now, I also want create/configure a Auth to the clients. I try "rewrite" the inialize()

```
//This is in my ClientsController.php
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'clients',
                'fields' => ['username' => 'client_email', 'password' => 'client_password']
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Clients',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Clients',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

With this, I receive this log(if uses parent::initalize() receive the same)

```
[RuntimeException] The "Auth" alias has already been loaded with the following config: array (...
```

I not want create a "Auth" manualy. How to use more of one Auth?

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reconfigure

You don't necessarily need to use multiple auth component instances, you can simply reconfigure it in the extended controller, using the components `config()` method, something along the lines of:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    // ...

    $this->Auth->config(
        [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'userModel' => 'clients',
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'client_email',
                        'password' => 'client_password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Clients',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Clients',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'storage' => [
                'className' => 'Session',
                'key' => 'Auth.Client'
            ]
        ],
        null,
        false
    );
}
```

**Note the use of the `storage` option**, you should define a different key here (the default is `Auth.User`), otherwise an authenticated client might be able to access the admin area and vice versa, as the user data would get stored in the same session key!

### Use aliasing

You could use multiple auth components if required, to do so you'd have to use aliasing, so that the components don't try to override each other:

```
$this->loadComponent('ClientAuth', [
    'className' => 'Auth',
    // ....
]);
```

**Don't forget to use a different session key in this case too!**

You'd access that component instance as `$this->ClientAuth` accordingly, and you may have to allow access to the `login()` method via `$this->Auth`, ie. in `ClientsController::initialize()` or `beforeFilter()` do:

```
$this->Auth->allow('login');
```

There might be further side-effects, so be careful.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Configuration options](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Aliasing Components](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#aliasing-components)**