# CakePHP3: how to use different authentication mechanisms?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I have a standard Form authentication declared in AppController.php:

```
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
           'Form' => [
                'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1]
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
           'controller' => 'Users',
           'action' => 'account'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Index',
            'action' => 'index'
        ]
    ]);
```

Now I want an authentication based on api_key in a webservice. The [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-basic-authentication), explains to do it like that:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Basic' => [
           'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key'],
            'userModel' => 'Users'
        ],
    ],
    'storage' => 'Memory',
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
]);
```

So now I wonder how to load the second authentication mechanism in my webservice. I tried to do that:

```
class DeviceconnectionsController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'authenticate' => [
                        'Basic' => [
                                'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key'],
                                'userModel' => 'Users'
                        ],
                ],
                'storage' => 'Memory',
                'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
        ]);
    }
    ....
}
```

But Cake complains that I try to **reload** a different Auth Component.
So maybe the right way is to load both authentication mechanisms in AppController.php like below:

```
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
           'Form' => [
                'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1]
            ],
            'Basic' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key'],
                'userModel' => 'Users'
            ],
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
           'controller' => 'Users',
           'action' => 'account'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Index',
            'action' => 'index'
        ]
    ]);
```

But it seems incorrect as both authentication uses a different `storage` and `unauthorizedRedirect` setting.

How to do?

Comment: Why do you think that would be "_incorrect_"? Also have you actually tried it? If so, what exactly is the problem? Also check **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers**, it states how multiple authentication handlers are processed, and shows how to configure them (it's being done just like in your example)

Comment: @ndm because by default loadComponent() configure `storage` to `session` and for basic api_key authentication, `storage` should be set to `memory`. And I don't see how to change this setting.

Comment: `Basic` authentication doesn't necessarily requires to use the `Memory` storage, you could of course also use the `Session` storage, which however will make it stateful. If you actually need stateful _and_ stateless authentication, then please point that out in your question, and explain your scenario a little more in-depth, ie why do you need both?, will both apply to the same resources (controllers/actions)?, etc...

Comment: @ndm thanks, I don't particularly need it. I just undertood that was the needed setting for basic authentication through api access. And in fact, api access to specific resources.

Comment: @ndm In fact I think that I need both stateful and stateless authentications. Default one (Form) for normal web access and one (Basic) for API access to some resources and the last one I need `'unauthorizedRedirect' => false`. AndI don't know how to set it.

Comment: Do these "_some resources_" overlap with the resources that should use stateful auth? Because that would actually be kinda tricky I guess.

Comment: @ndm. I suppose we can say that as it's the same base url and API controllers extends AppController. Do I need and APIController which extends Controller maybe?

Comment: As long as it's just about extending common controllers that already have auth configured, things should be fine, as you could just reconfigure it **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555876/various-this-auth-in-cakephp**. Of course you could also create further base controllers, that extend from `AppController`, so that auth doesn't have to be loaded there.